# Problems decrypting data in node.js (RSA PKCS 1.5)

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am having great difficulty implementing some encryption for a node.js project. I am using node-rsa which in turn uses the built in node crypto module.

My code appears to encrypt the data just fine and I can decrypt it. Unfortunately, the system I am sending the data to cannot. Having hit a bit of a wall I've tried decryption some data generated the other end. That also fails.

What is unusual in this case is that the data has to be encrypted using the PRIVATE key and decrypted using the PUBLIC key. As stupid as this is, I had no say in the decision to use this mechanism and it is already in wide use in a UK pubic transport ticketing system. So there is no possibility of doing anything different.

The specification [only] says:

> The payload data (Appendix A) is encrypted using the TIS private key,
>   using 1024Bit RSA PKCS#1v1.5. (This is a freely available public
>   standard). This protects a payload of up to 116 bytes, or 928Bits,
>   creating a 128 byte or 1024Bit encrypted output. The RSA encryption
>   algorithm adds a header of length 12 bytes to the payload before
>   encryption to improve security. For decryption purposes, this header
>   should be removed to get the correct payload.
>
> The format of this header is: 0x00 [10 non-zero bytes which are
>   padding] 0x00 [content]. This is often done automatically by
>   encryption/decryption software.

Here is an example public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDriuvWAKiTKFgmjHjHYjWK4IZ6
W1UOdrntxFAGT1szZlbKJfWGeBOPSk6MnW6AeX54zEta74Dnoj4MBT+MlekVQ2zp
G3qIZpp4DR+kF6eVRlguUg9l/Fgr9ZrFgkumCKIx/ccc6rvZcNvPnOVdPCBVoMRr
3X59WlLmH4d+RAivAQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I've derived this from the Modules / Exponent listed below... I think it is correct...?

Which is [supposedly] valid to decode this encrypted data:

```
1f876b22ea8af4341c4198347aabf1b1ba40649ad6918bbe26ebfcf4633786a2669ee499d796cf438a76ff0d4f6efc43f605994330e6fb88c8117eea6aad1a12c2525940f7b9946b3f6cbd674e2740070400ae6f2cf1ed6d36f610822a23d5a8a4717ecf671bf0530200f75a269951020be9f69a992d423f55eb6fefe6caa449
```

I get the following error:

```
decryptData error Error: Error during decryption (probably incorrect key). Original error: Error: error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01
```

I hate to say it, but I am now completely stumped. If anyone is able to decrypt that data using the supplied key and can explain how I would be very grateful.

Just to save the usual response to this sort of question that I see whenever anyone else has asked a similar question in the past. Please do not comment if all you want to say is the process is wrong. That is not helpful in any way. Just to confirm, whilst encryption with the private key is unusual, it is not impossible....It is supported by the RSA specification.

There are several ticket retailers who are encrypting their data this way and several scanning equipment manufacturers who are producing equipment that decrypts in this way. It's out there, it's working.

The only issue seems to be that there is some small mismatch between the encrypted data I am seeing from node-rsa (node.js crypto library) and the example data I have been given.

This is the original format the keys were given to me.....

Appendix D - Example Security Keys for Tickets
All example tickets are encrypted using the following fixed 1024Bit RSA key

(Never use these keys in production, you must generate your own key pair for this purpose as this private key cannot be considered secure and is for testing only)

```
Modulus = 16540368155253773454125654483794538435594869143015457768150677916704644349481001621163 93533906833356026635527060528398017212524170789714748325265707476885395169247950736258 76338137535298120673942399072260833758038152595105311260002268650951968659366409471762 707986435753824060971148933772149012757770173722369
= HEX [00eb8aeb d600a893 2858268c 78c76235 8ae0867a 5b550e76 b9edc450 064f5b33 6656ca25 f5867813 8f4a4e8c 9d6e8079 7e78cc4b 5aef80e7 a23e0c05 3f8c95e9 15436ce9 1b7a8866 9a780d1f a417a795 46582e52 0f65fc58 2bf59ac5 824ba608 a231fdc7 1ceabbd9 70dbcf9c e55d3c20 55a0c46b dd7e7d5a 52e61f87 7e4408af 01]
Public Exponent = 65537
= HEX [010001]
Private Exponent = 23262061627321059848127951748956201956280865601289878122136319690902346303487555417896 45421978315004119428666694674801184773156427997741861134011936129888508204465790901818 10860126020371138225614906842567831455763314175530505369901364910691824152015094858350 72189773434923487177372245370361799421231555208773
= HEX [21205394 b0590501 3a8c895a ff2797c2 255ba45f adf1afce ec5a9caa 96848c11 0b89b896 f44774f0 c5119103 1f246071 e209515b c3ad4c66 6bf582d3 72312f2b 7250fe61 f6abed7f e219c08d c3985ae1 3f6b6db2 0e3c040b df7a817d 14a5a6f1 20d94047 08512132 aca00baa 29805440 4ad5dec2 1bd544bb 8938c74b 2904e645]
```

Comment: I really strongly believe there is something mistaken there. There is no way you can decrypt something using the public key. It simply won't work. `The payload data (Appendix A) is encrypted using the TIS private key` I'd rather assume the meaning is `using the PKI key` which is *public key* for encryption. So you still need a private key of the keypar to decrypt the data.

Comment: That is a common misconception. Whilst it is certainly very unusual it does work and RSA encryption does permit this sort of operation.... As i said, this is already in wide use in a public transport ticket system. The data, in this case, is DEFINITELY encrypted with the PRIVATE key and decrypted with the public one.

Comment: I see that is possible - you can still "encrypt" the payload with the private key (doing decryption) to get "ciphertext" and decrypt with the public key (doing encryption), however this way provides very low security level (as the public key is .. public and derivable from the private key. What security possibly that schema provides? (I will check what the result is)

Comment: When I use that public key to “public decrypt” that message (you need to do a “raw” decryption, without padding), the result doesn’t match the padding scheme described (i.e. I get the the leading byte as 0x66, not 0x00), which suggests a different key was used.

Comment: Also, that specification is only partially complete. The actual RSA heading / padding for PKCS v1.5 encryption (for 1024 bit keys) is 0x00, 0x02, <9 non-zero bytes>, 0x00 and for signatures it is similar but that second byte is 0x01. Your error message says "block type is not 01” which suggests your code is looking for  a signature. As this appears to be a non-standard use of RSA, you might need to use “raw” RSA operations and check / remove the padding yourself.

Comment: indeed, regardless I try encrypt or decrypt with the public key I won't get the valid PKCS1 padding (you are right,  RSA allows me decryption op with the public key). It means you have wrong data or wrong key :)

Comment: I must admit, I am not convinced any of the examples I have been given are correct... I've just added the original key info I was given (Modulus / Exponent) from which I generated the PEM format public key. I'd really like the private key, but as far as I know I cannot create that from just the modules and exponent. (Or can I?).

Comment: Unfortunately, the people who should be helping me (the ones the spec comes from) have no intention of doing so as my client is not really in their favour...they simply say that other retailers have implemented this given that [limited] specification, so I should be able to as well! Incredibly frustrating! I think the best I can hope for is some community agreement that the examples are not valid. With some evidence that they are proving rubbish my client may be able to force their hand somewhat....possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm... I was given incorrect data.